# Storing Pandas DataFrame to HDF5 with both axes MultiIndexed

Tags: python, pandas

I would think that storing a DataFrame with both MultiIndexed axes should be possible. However, I am getting the following error:

```
In [1]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Foo', 'Bar'],['One','Two','Three']])
        column = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo', 'bar'],['one','two','three']])
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,6), index=index, columns=column)
        df
Out[1]:                 foo                                    bar
                        one          two          three        one          two          three
        Foo     One     0.605352     0.882382     0.472946     0.615619     0.108022     0.389674
                Two     0.746384     0.594509     0.556881     0.457000     0.529793     0.929574
                Three   0.270978     0.956778     0.515201     0.626850     0.852708     0.861962
        Bar     One     0.219994     0.648191     0.677824     0.408439     0.079326     0.414059
                Two     0.186167     0.767103     0.880667     0.205253     0.647471     0.449379
                Three   0.353171     0.249900     0.723791     0.458349     0.977604     0.691188

In [2]: with pd.HDFStore('test.h5', 'w') as store:
            store.append('output', df)
Out[2]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-55-87e96c141a7f> in <module>()
              1 with pd.HDFStore('test.h5', 'w') as store:
        ----> 2     store.append('output', df)

        /home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in append(self, key, value, format, append, columns, dropna, **kwargs)
            917         kwargs = self._validate_format(format, kwargs)
            918         self._write_to_group(key, value, append=append, dropna=dropna,
        --> 919                              **kwargs)
            920 
            921     def append_to_multiple(self, d, value, selector, data_columns=None,

        /home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in _write_to_group(self, key, value, format, index, append, complib, encoding, **kwargs)
           1262 
           1263         # write the object
        -> 1264         s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
           1265 
           1266         if s.is_table and index:

        /home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in write(self, obj, data_columns, **kwargs)
           4195                 data_columns.insert(0, n)
           4196         return super(AppendableMultiFrameTable, self).write(
        -> 4197             obj=obj, data_columns=data_columns, **kwargs)
           4198 
           4199     def read(self, **kwargs):

        /home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in write(self, obj, axes, append, complib, complevel, fletcher32, min_itemsize, chunksize, expectedrows, dropna, **kwargs)
           3785         self.create_axes(axes=axes, obj=obj, validate=append,
           3786                          min_itemsize=min_itemsize,
        -> 3787                          **kwargs)
           3788 
           3789         for a in self.axes:

        /home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in create_axes(self, axes, obj, validate, nan_rep, data_columns, min_itemsize, **kwargs)
           3383             axis, axis_labels = self.non_index_axes[0]
           3384             data_columns = self.validate_data_columns(
        -> 3385                 data_columns, min_itemsize)
           3386             if len(data_columns):
           3387                 mgr = block_obj.reindex_axis(

        /home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in validate_data_columns(self, data_columns, min_itemsize)
           3246         if info.get('type') == 'MultiIndex' and data_columns:
           3247             raise ValueError("cannot use a multi-index on axis [{0}] with "
        -> 3248                              "data_columns {1}".format(axis, data_columns))
           3249 
           3250         # evaluate the passed data_columns, True == use all columns

        ValueError: cannot use a multi-index on axis [1] with data_columns ['level_1', 'level_0']
```

It makes most sense for me to store the data like this. Mainly because my needs will vary hugely. For some applications I will need all rows and all columns. For many others, I will only need all rows, and one parent column: say I would need all rows under `foo`. I might also need only one parent row and one parent column: `Foo, foo`.

I will certainly need all secondary rows and columns.

In my case, primary row indexes are States, secondary row indexes are sensor names, primary column indexes are the different things sensed, and secondary column indexes are statistics of the sensor outputs. Therefore, it is easy to see that I might need data for just one type of sensing for all states, or for just one state, or I might need all things sensed from one state, or all states.

I am looking for either a fix to the error, or a better way to store the data.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem you had is related to the one I just encountered. I posted my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/44121688/3154588 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up stacking the DataFrame once, to get rid of the MultiIndex in the columns before storing:

```
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5', 'w') as store:
    store.append('output', df.stack().astype(float))
```

It is not ideal, but the [querying](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#querying) capabilities of the HDF5 tables compensates for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you enforce `format='fixed'` when storing your `df` you can keep your MultiIndex:

```
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5', 'w') as store:
    store.put('output', df, format='fixed')
    print store['output']

              foo                     bar                
              one     two   three     one     two   three
Foo One    0.9626  0.9761  0.4385  0.2976  0.0882  0.7589
    Two    0.7842  0.7563  0.4796  0.5664  0.1511  0.9345
    Three  0.3364  0.4271  0.4107  0.9009  0.5207  0.4082
Bar One    0.9892  0.4595  0.1485  0.1456  0.9935  0.1386
    Two    0.3187  0.7908  0.2947  0.7354  0.5759  0.9102
    Three  0.0499  0.1865  0.8113  0.4815  0.1427  0.3322
```

But you will loose some capabilities (for example, to use `.append()` method). Which might or might not be a problem depending on your needs.

Comment: It would be a problem, because my sensor information gets updated. With fixed format tables, I'll have to recreate them every time I can get away with changing values, and adding new columns or rows.

Comment: When you say `my sensor information gets updated` do you mean that records already existing in `store` get updated or you mean adding non-duplicated records?

Comment: Both. The number of sensors I have is constant. So I don't expect to ever add rows. But based on incoming data, I will be updating the values already there, and I might add a column with a different statistic once a while.

Comment: Are you aware that `.append()` does NOT check for duplicates and you will have to manually delete the records that you need to change to avoid duplicates?