# Store multi-index pandas dataframe with hdf5 table format

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I just came across this issue when adding a multi-index to my pandas dataframe. I am using the pandas [HDFStore](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables) with the option `format='table'`, which I prefer because the saved data frame is easier to understand and load when not using pandas. (For details see this SO answer: [Save pandas DataFrame using h5py for interoperabilty with other hdf5 readers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30773073/3154588) .)

But I ran into a problem because I was setting the multi-index using `drop=False` when calling [set_index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787168/3154588), which keeps the index columns as dataframe columns. This was fine until I put the dataframe to the store using `format='table'`. Using `format='fixed'` worked fine. But `format='table'` gave me an error with duplicate column names. I avoided the error by dropping the redundant columns before putting and restoring the columns after getting.

Here is the write/read pair of functions that I now use:

```
def write_df_without_index_columns(store, name, df):
    if isinstance(df.index, pd.MultiIndex):
        # drop any columns that are duplicates of index columns
        redundant_columns = set(df.index.names).intersection(set(df.columns))
        if redundant_columns:
            df = df.copy(deep=True)
            df.drop(list(redundant_columns), axis=1, inplace=True)

    store.put(name, df,
              format='table',
              data_columns=True)

def read_df_add_index_columns(store, name, default_value):
    df = store.get(name)
    if isinstance(df.index, pd.MultiIndex):
        # remember the MultiIndex column names
        index_columns = df.index.names
        # put the MultiIndex columns into the data frame
        df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
        # now put the MultiIndex columns back into the index
        df.set_index(index_columns, drop=False, inplace=True)
    return df
```

My question: is there a better way to do this? I expect to have a data frame with millions of rows, so I do not want this to be too inefficient.